# how to change rootviewcontroller of NavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have navigationController which is presented as modalview and whose rootviewcontroller is say FirstViewController.At some point I want to change rootviewcontroller of navigationController to SecondViewController.What I did is

```
[self.navigationController initWithRootViewController:SecondViewController];
```

I am not sure what I did is correct and whether or not FirstViewController got released?Please anyone know what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Do either

```
[firstViewController.navigationController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObject: secondViewController] 
                                                    animated: YES];
```

or

```
firstViewController.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject: secondViewController];
```

where `firstViewController` is an instance of `FirstViewController` and `secondViewController` is an instance of `SecondViewController` classes, respectively. The latter variant is a shortcut for `setViewControllers:animated:` without animation.

Comment: Thanks Costique! It's working.Can you please explain how setViewController works?

Comment: Both the methods replace the whole view controller stack inside the navigation controller. The "old" controllers get released. The stack array begins with the root controller and its last element is the topmost view controller.

Comment: @Costique How can I set Root ... suppose i have to change root 3 times then will this methods works efficiently or not ?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) changeRootViewControllerOFNavigationControlllerAtRuntime:(UIViewController *) viewController {

     UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController=navController; 
}
```

Comment: Write some content which explain your answer.

Comment: This will remove all the settings you could have had in the original navigationController.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
fileprivate func changeRootVC() {
        if let newVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyStoryboardID"), let nc = self.navigationController {
            nc.setViewControllers([newVC], animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way, calling `init` on an already initialized object rarely (i think never) is.

The way i solved this issue, is to create a subclass of UINavigationController.

In this subclass, i overwrite the `initwithrootviewcontroller:`

```
- (id) initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    UIViewController *fakeController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    self = [super initWithRootViewController:fakeController];
    if(self)
    {
        self.fakeRootViewController = fakeController;
        rootViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

        [self pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The fakeRootViewController actually does nothing, it's a workaround for iOS not having a possibility to set the rootviewcontroller.

In another function (setRootViewController: aViewController) you hide the backbutton of the new 'rootviewcontroller' so the user never sees that there is a fake rootviewcontroller. and then push it above the fakerootviewcontroller

The poptorootviewcontroller should be overwritten to make sure it always pops to index 1 of the stack, not index 0.

The getter of viewcontrollers should be changed so it returns an array without the fakerootviewcontroller (`removeobjectatindex: 0`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The answer of @Costique only sets the navigationcontroller of the rootviewcontroller. This will leave you with a stack within a stack etc.. In my case, i needed support for popToRootViewController (with a tabbaritem) so this didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make custom UINavigationController

```
@interface mySwitchRootViewNavigationController()

@property (nonatomic, retain) myFirstViewController * FirstViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) mySecondViewController * SecondViewController;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.FirstViewController = [[myFirstViewController alloc] init];
  self.SecondViewController = [[mySecondViewController alloc] init];
}

-(void) setRootViewControllerWithID:(int) viewControllerID
{
  if (viewControllerID == 1) {
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.SecondViewController];
  } else
  {
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.FirstViewController];
  }
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self setRootViewControllerWithID:intVar];
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

initialization

```
mySwitchRootViewNavigationController * switchView = [mySwitchRootViewNavigationController alloc] init];
```